# Ignore from the submitted url the form elements that do not have any values

Tags: php

I want to create a url in the form of domain.com/?product=value1&product2=value2.....

Sometimes the textboxes may not have values in it. How can I edit the code below to ignore those forms elements?

**my form**

```
    <form action="customsearch.php">

    <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="product" name="product">
    <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="product2" name="product2">
.
.
.    
    <input type="submit" value="Send">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Re your updated question: You *can* redirect from server side to a new, nicer URL, but I'm not sure this makes sense. It would  probably be better to do this in JavaScript.

You could use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

```
$url = http_build_query($_POST);
```

as @David Fells points out, this will however not remove empty values.

You *could* do a

```
$post_elements = array_filter($_POST, "strlen");
$url = http_build_query($post_elements );
```

which is just as well, but don't do this with large amounts of data.

Also, if I were you, I would do this using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

note that if you're planning to use this for a GET request, the overall size of the data shouldn't exceed 2-4 kilobytes due to server side and browser side restrictions on the maximum length of URLs.

Comment: Hi Pekka, I have updated my question because I think I am doing a mistake and want to start it over.

Comment: That will not exclude empty values, which is what he requested

Comment: @Mikey as @David already says, you can't do this on PHP side without using complicated redirections. Better do this in JavaScript on client side

Comment: @Mikey that's worth a new question, this one is completely focused on the PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)
{
  if ('' == $v) {
    $url .= "&".urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v);
  }
} 
?>
```

Don't use "if ($v)" because if someone enters a 0 into a field, it won't add it. You just want to test '', empty string.

Comment: Hi David, I have updated my question because I think I am doing a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new answer since the question was entirely changed...

There's no reason for this. Browsers construct query strings based on standards. If youw ant to ignore empty fields on the backend, do so. If for some stylistic reason you just can't stand them there, then use jQuery and manually construct the URL and redirect to it on click - but this is not the expected or normal way to submit a form.

Comment: So on-the-fly using PHP there is no way to avoid the domain.com/?product=&product2=abs&product3=&product4= ?

Comment: Nope. By the time PHP sees it, the form is submitted back with that URL. If you want to stop it from ever appearing in the URL at all it's a client side thing.

Comment: This is all true, but I can somewhat understand the desire for a search form to generate clean URLs. The easiest answer to this is JavaScript.